# CSS border variation with transparency

Tags: html, css, transparency, border

I'm trying to make an HTML/CSS menu in which the active link is indicated by a section of transparency (a pointer notched out of the border), to reveal the image behind the menu.

This is what I'm going for: http://larsakerson.com/northendgreenway/beta3.html

But with this sort of notched pointer: http://larsakerson.com/northendgreenway/beta2.html

Is there any way to do this in CSS (either 2.1 or 3), or is a strictly image-based menu the only way to make this work?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking - you can add/remove a background as needed, but I don't think there is a way to "notch" a CSS border.

Comment: the only way I know would be to use an image...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a notched corner using borders like so...

```
div {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-width: 20px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-color:  transparent blue blue blue;
   background: transparent; 
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ytGQn/).

Refer to the jsFiddle and notice the top corner is letting the background through. Simply adapt this example to your site.

Comment: nice. practically the same thing. but you are faster than i.

Answer (score 1):

here you go dude. http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/vnNXW/
just change .trapezoid to .active:active{}

```
.trapezoid { 

    display:block;

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    width:1px; 

    height:1px;

    background:transparent;

    border-style: solid;

     border-color:transparent #eee #eee #eee;

    border-width: 50px 50px 50px 50px;

}
```

and change the border-sizes to fit. 
for .active{border-color:transparent}